# How to add a progress bar while using pypeln

Tags: python

Could anyone give me a hint i could use a progress bar in this using tqdm or any other ?

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession, TCPConnector
import asyncio
import pypeln as pl

limit = 500
users = list(range(1,99999))

async def fetch(users, session):
    print(users)

pl.task.each(
    fetch,
    users,
    workers=limit,
    on_start=lambda: dict(session=ClientSession(connector=TCPConnector(limit=None,ssl=False))),
    on_done=lambda session: session.close(),
    run=True,
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around it.. i hope this would help someone.

```py
from aiohttp import ClientSession, TCPConnector
import asyncio
import pypeln as pl
from tqdm.asyncio import trange, tqdm
import time

limit = 1
users = list(range(1,10))

async def fetch(users, session):
    time.sleep(1)
    pbar.update(1)

with tqdm(total=len(users)) as pbar:
    pl.task.each(
        fetch,
        users,
        workers=limit,
        on_start=lambda: dict(session=ClientSession(connector=TCPConnector(limit=None,ssl=False))),
        on_done=lambda session: session.close(),
        run=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tqdm.asyncio`](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/asyncio/) module.

```py
from tqdm.asyncio import trange, tqdm
async for i in trange(len(users)):
   pl.task.each(
      fetch,
      users,
      workers=limit,
      on_start=lambda: dict(session=ClientSession(connector=TCPConnector(limit=None,ssl=False))),
      on_done=lambda session: session.close(),
    run=True,
   )
```

Comment: am getting the error below
`    async for i in trange(len(users)):`
`    ^`
`SyntaxError: 'async for' outside async function`

Comment: yea you have to use use an async function if you want to use await

Comment: @crissal could you show me how to apply that on the full code i gave ? i have tried using a `async def main()` and calling it, now it shows the progress bar now, but doesn't progress